# Java 8 Optional get if present

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a class structure like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private FooB fooB;

    public Optional<FooB> getFooB() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(fooB);
    }
}

public class FooB {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
main() {
    //initialize a Foo object called foo
    String a = foo.getFooB().ifPresent(FooB::getA);
}
```

Basically if the foo object returns FooB as present then get the field `String a` from `FooB` and store it in the local variable `String a`. How can I do this elegantly in 1 line?

Comment: The question is: what do you want to happen if `Optional<FooB>` is empty? That is exactly what Optional is for: force you to think about that case.

Comment: `ifPresent()` needs a consumer which cannot return anything. While you could give it a stateful consumer it is most likely better to read to use `map()`. You just need to deal with the resulting `Optional<String>` again: `String a = foo.getFooB().map(FooB::getA).orElse(null);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `getFooB()` returns an instance of `Optional<FooB>`, to get the corresponding value of `getA()`, you need to use the [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method as next:

```
Optional<String> a = foo.getFooB().map(FooB::getA);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
String a = foo.getFooB().isPresent() ? foo.getFooB().get().getA() : {absolutely anything your heart desires if FooB doesn't exist};
```

Comment: This is horrible. And it assumes that OP wants to have `null` when the Optional is empty.

Comment: is it less horrible after my edit?

Comment: Nope. There is the `map` operation on `Optional` for that.

Comment: foo.getFooB().map(FooB::getA).orElse(/* Whatever OP wants. */);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13229586)